# How to maintain Cursor position in Delphi after replacing line breaks

Tags: delphi, replace, cursor

I have a DBMemo with Name = dbmemSummary And one method ReplaceLineBreaks which will be removing extra line breaks from DB Memo. I am facing problem with setting cursor position.

This is method snippet -

```
procedure ReplaceLineBreaks;
var
  Save_Cursor: TCursor;
  aOldTextList: TStringList;
  aNewTextList: TStringList;
  i, : Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  aOldTextList := TStringList.Create;
  aNewTextList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Save_Cursor := Screen.Cursor;
    aOldTextList.text := dbmemDisciplineSummary.text;
    for i := 0 to aOldTextList.Count - 1 do begin
      if (i = 0) and( Trim(aOldTextList[i]) <> '') then
        aNewTextList.Add(aOldCN_TextList[i])
      else if not ((i<>0) and (Trim(aOldTextList[i - 1]) = '') and (Trim(aOldTextList[i]) = '')) then
        aNewTextList.Add(aOldTextList[i]);
    end;
    cdsPTClinicalNotesCNTEXT.AsString := aNewTextList.Text;
  finally
    Screen.Cursor := Save_Cursor;
    FreeAndNil(aOldTextList);
    FreeAndNil(aNewTextList);
  end;
end;
```

But its is not setting cursor back to same position ... Can some one please help ?

Comment: TCursor is the mouse pointer, not the memo caret, which some people call a cursor.  You'll want to look into the memo SelStart property for the caret position. You'll need to track that as you remove lines. Personally I would use split the memo text into left and right of the selstart position and remove lines separately with StringReplace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Memo's `SelStart` and `SelLength` properties, not the `Screen.Cursor` property:

```
procedure ReplaceLineBreaks;
var
  Save_SelStart, Save_SelLength: Integer;
  aOldTextList: TStringList;
  aNewTextList: TStringList;
  i, : Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  aOldTextList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    aNewTextList := TStringList.Create;
    try
      aOldTextList.Text := dbmemDisciplineSummary.Text;
      for i := 0 to aOldTextList.Count - 1 do begin
        if (i = 0) and( Trim(aOldTextList[i]) <> '') then
          aNewTextList.Add(aOldCN_TextList[i])
        else if not ((i<>0) and (Trim(aOldTextList[i - 1]) = '') and (Trim(aOldTextList[i]) = '')) then
          aNewTextList.Add(aOldTextList[i]);
      end;
      Save_SelStart := dbmemDisciplineSummary.SelStart;
      Save_SelLength := dbmemDisciplineSummary.SelLength;
      try
        cdsPTClinicalNotesCNTEXT.AsString := aNewTextList.Text;
      finally
        dbmemDisciplineSummary.SelStart := Save_SelStart;
        dbmemDisciplineSummary.SelLength := Save_SelLength;
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(aNewTextList);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(aOldTextList);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Its not considering the number of lines which has been Removed. Post execution of this if we have extra blank line spaces there. It will be removed but cursor will not be pointing to same position where user has edited the text. Instead of that it is capturing exact location of cursor and putting it on same place without considering extra lines removal.